# Shorten each do rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to shorten this code:

```
<% childrens.each do |children| %>
    <% dad = children.dad %>

    <tr>
        <td><%= dad.first_name %><%= dad.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= children.city %></td>
   <tr>

    ....
```

Is there a way to somehow write it like that:

```
 <% childrens.each do |children, dad| %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Nope, there's no simple way to do that. :)

Comment: As `dad` is one of your column names, you cannot do that as you iterate over an array belonging to a model, which I guess in your case is `Children`

Comment: @VladBalanescu: it _is_ possible to have `|child, dad|` in that block, but the code will be more complex than what he has already. :)

Comment: What if you group children by dad?, that way you can yield dad in the block

Comment: You may do `childrens = childrens.map{|c| [c, c.dad]}`. That will allow you to iterate as you want. But, this is totally bad way as @SergioTulentsev said